# Using multiple model associations with bindings

Tags: extjs, associations

I am using ExtJS 6.x with three models:

```
Ext.define('Admin.model.Patient', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
        'Ext.data.schema.Association'
    ],

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'mrn', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'birth_date', type: 'date', format: 'Y-m-d' },
        { name: 'sex', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'first_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'last_name', type: 'string' },

    ],

    style: {
        'font-size': '22px',
        'color':'red'
    },

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: remote.url.patient, 

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
        }
    }

});

Ext.define('Admin.model.LabResultGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'test_code', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'test_name', type: 'string' },
        {
            name: 'patient_id',
            type: 'string',
            reference: {
                parent: 'Patient',
                inverse: 'lab_results',
                autoLoad: false
            }
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: remote.url.labsgroup,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
    }
});
```

and

```
Ext.define('Admin.model.LabResult', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'test_code', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'test_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'test_code_system', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'result_value', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'result_value_num', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'collection_datetime', type: 'date', format: 'Y-m-d' },
        { name: 'result_datetime', type: 'date', format: 'Y-m-d' },
        {
            name: 'lab_id',
            type: 'string',
            reference: {
                parent: 'LabResultGroup',
                inverse: 'lab_group',
                autoLoad: false
            }
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: remote.url.labs,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
        }
    }
});
```

I can access the association between LabResultGroup and Patient just fine (between two comboboxes using bindings), but when I try accessing the association between LabResult and LabResultGroup, it does not register.

I will post a Fiddle in due course to exhibit the behavior I am encountering. Is there anything that would prevent associations across models like this?

Answer (score 0):

It actually worked! For some odd reason the parent name in the association on my LabResult model got mucked up. Corrected that, and my association bindings are firing as expected.

(Also, there was a minor problem with the API endpoint I was accessing. I had to add another condition for the property on which it was filtering. Details, shmetails)

Moral of the story: Names are important! Happy Friday peeps! Ha! Ha!